# getting jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError even after passing argument books in render_template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

> application.py

```
import os

from flask import (Flask, session, render_template, request, redirect, flash)
from flask_session import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

app = Flask(__name__)

# Configure session to use filesystem
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)
engine = create_engine(..., pool_pre_wing=True)
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
@app.route("/")
def index():
    books = db.execute('SELECT * FROM books').fetchall()
    return render_template('signup.html', books = books)
```

> signup.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for book in books %}
                        <div class = "col-md-6 d-none d-lg-block pl-1 float-right">
                            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="200" height="auto" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "col-md-6 d-flex flex-column mb-3 py-2 pl-0 pr-3 ">
                            <h4 class = "my-2">{{book.title}}</h4>
                            <p>A book review is a form of literary criticism in which a book is merely described or analyzed based on content, style, and merit. A book review may be a primary source, opinion piece, summary review or scholarly review</p>
                            <a href="#" class = "button btn-sm"> Check Book</a>
                        </div>
        {% endfor %}
{% endblock%}
```

> Error
> *jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError
> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'book' is undefined*

*even if i remove books = books argument in render_template(), am still getting the above error*

Comment: try to remove `__pycache__` and re run your app.

Comment: i removed __pycache__ but still getting the same error

Comment: Are you getting the error from `{% for book in books %}` or `{{book.title}}`?

Comment: from `{{book.title}}`